# Custom exception class does not catch exceptions

Tags: java, exception

I have a Custom exception class which extends Exception class (like below).

```
public class SomeABCException extends Exception
```

But, when I use this `SomeABCException` in all places where I previously used `Exception` in the catch block, it does not catch the Exceptions even after it extends `Exception` class itself.

E.g. if a parent/caller method has a catch block as below

```
catch (Exception e) {
    TODO something;
}
```

and if I have a child method as below in which I am running some database queries.

```
try {
    Some database queries;
} catch (SomeABCException e) {
    throw new SomeABCException (e.getMessage(),"I/O or SQL_EXCEPTION");
}
```

Here if the sql connection fails, the catch is not able to catch the exceptions, rather it gets caught in the parent/callers catch block which uses System.Exception to catch it.

During the debug, it does not go to the throw in the catch block on child method.

Please explain, I do not understand it.

Comment: Please get rid of the misplaced `***` in your code posts above as they are quite distracting. Also note that if a code block does not throw **your exception** then your exception will not be caught.

Comment: Actually if SomeABCException  is extending Exception class and if there is an com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException, then it should be caught by the SomeABCException  catch block right?

Comment: That is so very very wrong. I'm afraid that you are misunderstanding how exceptions work. Please read the many answers below as well as having a look at the tutorials on exceptions as I have a feeling a light will come on in a few minutes where you will see the error of your assumptions. Luck.

Comment: Very true, got it now...Thanks for help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are thinking backwards. Instances of `Exception` will only catch exceptions that are subclasses, or instances of it. So, since `Exception` is a **superclass** of `SomeABCException`, the `SQLException` will NOT be caught.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
try {
    //Some database queries; -> this will throw Exception
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new SomeABCException (e.getMessage(),"I/O or SQL_EXCEPTION");
}
```

You are catching `SomeABCException` when your "some database queries" are not throwing that kind of exception (maybe some `SQLException` or something like that)

Answer (score 1):

It happens because the method that you are using doesn't throw the `SomeABCException`

Pay attention that all exceptions extend the `Exception` class.

Let me explain you with an example:

```
public void mymethod() throws IOException{
   //...
}
```

In your code if you try to do:

```
try{
    myObj.myMethod()
} catch (NumberFormatException ne){
   //... 
}
```

you will not able to compile. In any case the code inside the catch will never call.

Answer (score 1):

If your  "**some database queries**" method does not throw a "SomeABCException" there's no way to catch an exception that is not thrown.

```
try {
    Some database queries;
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new SomeABCException (e.getMessage(),"I/O or SQL_EXCEPTION");
}
```

"Exception e" should be an specific exception.
Or if you want make your queries throw the exception so you can catch your custom exception just like you did.

```
try {
    Some database queries; // Make sure this method throws your custom exception
} catch (SomeABCException e) {
    //do something else with the exception.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Hovercraft mentioned - it doesnt work that way. Check this example:

```
class ExceptionA extends Exception {}

class ExceptionB extends Exception {}

class ExceptionC extends ExceptionB {}

try {
  //some code that throws ExceptionA
} catch (Exception ex) {
   //will work
}


try {
  //some code that throws ExceptionB
} catch (ExceptionA ex) {
  //will not work
}

try {
  //some code that throws ExceptionC
} catch (ExceptionB ex) {
   //that will work
}
```

So bassically You can catch only exceptions that are throwed in try block or its ancestors.